# GitHub API: Does a webhook fire on a pull request approval event?

Tags: github, github-api

I need the ability to kick-off a process via a webhook whenever a pull request review is marked 'approved'. I know there's a way to query a pull request via the API to determine state, number of approvals, etc., but that doesn't help. I am looking for a way to invoke a process as soon as, and every time, someone approves a request. It doesn't appear this particular event triggers a webhook though. Is that correct? Is there a way to accomplish this otherwise?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For your use-case, there is an option on GitHub to send Webhook events on **Pull request reviews**.

On a GitHub repo, if you go to **Settings -> Webhooks -> Add a webhook**, and over there select the option shown below

[image]

You can select the webhook to be triggered on **Pull request reviews** as below

[image]

Once you have the webhook set up, whenever a pull request review is submitted, edited or dismissed, a [PullRequestReviewEvent](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#pullrequestreviewevent) is triggered (sample webhook payload in the web-link provided), and the webhook payload will have the **state** of the review. In case the review is approved, the **state** value would be **approved** as shown in the payload snapshot below.

[image]

You can then have the logic of triggering any event/process based on the **state** value in the webhook payload.